# PHPMailer отправляет не все поля

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

На сайте есть 2 контактные формы, одна в попапе, вторая просто на странице. Я прописываю один код для двух(привожу ниже) и возникают следующие проблемы:
1) в письмах приходят только первые 3 поля, adress и comments приходят пустые
2) в обычной форме проходит проверка заполненности полей перед отправкой, в попапе почему-то нет, хотя код одинаковый на двух страницах
Предполагаю что это из-за ajax запроса, но нет идей как это исправить

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="form" action="send.php" name="volt-form">
    <ul class="contact-form-list">
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="userName" type="text" name="name" class="input" value="" required placeholder="Your name">
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="userSurname" type="text" name="surname" class="input" value="" required placeholder="Surname">
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="userTel" type="tel" name="phone" class="input" value="" required placeholder="Phone number">
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="userEmail" type="email" name="email" class="input" value="" required placeholder="Email">
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="userAdress" type="text" name="adress" class="input" value="" required placeholder="Adress">
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item">
            <textarea id="userComments" type="text" name="comments" class="input input-textarea" value=""
                                    required placeholder="Comments">
            </textarea>
        </li>
        <li class="contact-form-list__item contact-form-list__item">
            <input id="formSubmit" type="submit" class="contact-form__btn button button--sm "
                                    value="Make an Order">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

```js
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'send.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: new FormData(this),
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == true) {
                    $('#cfModalThx').addClass('cf-modal-submit');
                    $('#cfModal').removeClass('cf-modal-show');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$text = $_POST['adress'];
$text = $_POST['comments'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'example@gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'example@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = ssl;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'example');
     $mail->addAddress("example@gmail.com", 'example');
    $mail->addReplyTo('example@gmail.com', 'example');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New order from the site Volt';
    $mail->Body    =    "<b>Name:</b> $name <br>
                        <b>Surame:</b> $surname<br><br>
                        <b>Phone:</b> $phone<br><br>
                        <b>E-mail:</b> $email<br><br>
                        <b>Adress:</b><br> $adress<br><br>
                        <b>Comments:</b><br> $comments<br><br>";

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: Хм, я бы данные формы перед отправкой сериализовал на всякий случай, но это офтоп.

Comment: @Quazimorda я просто совсем не дружу с js, поэтому код js взят с просторов интернета. не подскажите, каким образом я могу сделать сериализацию?

Comment: Как минимум, в javascript строчку  data: new FormData(this), заменил бы на  data: new FormData(this.serialize()),
а в php перед тем, как присваивать переменные, которые отправил пользователь, вывел бы на экран всё, что прилетело в $_POST.

Comment: @Quazimorda на this.serialize() ругается

Comment: Бог с ним, оставьте как было, что выводится на экран из $_POST?

Comment: Блин, у вас же нет переменных $adress и $comments. У вас присваиваются данные оба раза в переменную $text

Comment: @Quazimorda увидела, вот она невнимательность. Огромное спасибо)Подскажите, пожалуйста, может знаете ответ на второй вопрос?
 2) в обычной форме проходит проверка заполненности полей перед отправкой, в попапе почему-то нет, хотя код одинаковый на двух страницах

Comment: Сложно сказать точно, но меня смущает вот какая деталь. Вы пишете, что код самих форм у вас одинаковый. Возможно к делу проверки это и не относится, однако у вас имеются две формы в рамках одной страницы, которые обе имеют один и тот же id="form". Такого не следует допускать. Идентификатор обязан быть уникальным в пределах всей страницы. Нужны разные id, а функцию $('#form').on('submit',.. следует переписать так, чтобы она отправляла данные из обеих форм. То есть привязать к селектору form, а не к id.

Comment: И ещё, с проверкой следует проверить как написан класс. В строчке $mail = new PHPMailer(true); вы создаёте объект класса PHPMailer. Надо смотреть как он написан и в нём ли происходит проверка. Но это уже лучше вынести в отдельный вопрос, на этом ресурсе не любят, когда задаются несколько вопросов сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы присваиваете:

```
$text = $_POST['adress'];
$text = $_POST['comments'];
```

А пытаетесь использовать:

```
<b>Adress:</b><br> $adress<br><br>
<b>Comments:</b><br> $comments<br><br>";
```